# Print page in landscape

Tags: php, html, css, dhtml

I have an PHP page with information [tables , data ] When user click on print I want it to be printed in Landscape[ view 70%]  how to do it programmatically ?

I tried some css rotation of page but didn't work out.

Comment: The @page rule and forcing Landscape orientation:  http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets

Comment: @Haim beat you to the punch :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets#The_.40page_rule_and_forcing_Landscape_orientation

This will help you out.